# Tablesorter sort numbers

Tags: jquery

I have the problem with the jquery table sorter. This is my code;

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: "fancyNumber",
            is: function (s) {
                return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/./g, ''));
            },
            type: "numeric"
        });

        $("#mi-tabla").tablesorter({
            headers: { 0: { sorter: 'fancyNumber'} },
            widgets: ['zebra']
        });
    });
```

The problem is it order like this:

1.010.336 - 1.067.205 - 1.114 - 1.118.310

It should be:

1.114 - 1.010.336 - 1.067.205 - 1.118.310

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: "number",
            is: function (s) {
                return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[.]/g), ""));
            },
            type: "numeric"
        });

         jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: "time",
            is: function (s) {
                return true;
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[:]/g), ""));
            },
            type: "numeric"
        });

        $("#miTable").tablesorter({
            headers: { 
                2: { sorter: 'number'},
                4: { sorter: 'number'} ,
                7: { sorter: 'number'} ,
                9: { sorter: 'time'} ,
            },
            widgets: ['zebra']
        });
    });
```

With this you can sort correctly the numbers with separator .(2, 4 y 7)

But I want also that sort the field 9

Field 9 do this

02:32 - 02:27 - 32:00 - 24:52 - 29:08- 28:01

And it should be:

32:00 - 29:08 - 28:01 - 24:52 - 02:32 - 02:27

Any ideas?

Thanks